# Binding csv data to a chart in C# - Enumeration Exception

Tags: c#, csv, charts, enumeration

I have problems to bind the Y-Value to a chart. I have following code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var date = new List<String>();
        var forecast = new List<Double>();

        string dir = @"C:\Main\test.csv";

        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dir))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var fields = line.Split(new Char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                date.Add(fields[0]);
                if (fields.Length > 1)
                    value.Add(Convert.ToDouble(fields[1]));
            }
        }

        String[] _date = date.ToArray();
        Double[] _value = value.ToArray();


        chart1.Series["Test"].Points.DataBindXY(_date,_value);
        chart1.Series["Test"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;

      }
```

The Y-value has to be a double. So after convertion I get another error (System.InvalidOperationException) and he tells me that the Enumeration was already finished/ has already terminated. What's wrong? Before the Convertion of the Value Array to double he couldn't bind the Y-value because it was not a double.

Comment: is your xAxis an array of strings? you may want it to be of type `DateTime`! may be

Comment: No, that should work but I think I have found the error but don't know how to solve it. The date array contains date and values separated by semicolon. The value array is empty!

Comment: by the way , I don't seem to see the list called `value`?

Comment: Fixed! I just had to change the "," to ";" - how can I skip the first row because it's a headline for the columns.